# Print values from list based from separate text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I print a list of words from a separate text file? I want to print all the words unless the word has a length of 4 characters.

words.txt file looks like this:

abate  chicanery   disseminate gainsay latent  aberrant    coagulate   dissolution garrulous   laud

It has 334 total words in it. I'm trying to display the list until it reaches a word with a length of 4 and stops.

```
wordsFile = open("words.txt", 'r')
words = wordsFile.read()
wordsFile.close()
wordList = words.split()

#List outputs length of words in list

lengths= [len(i) for i in wordList]
for i in range(10):
    if i >= len(lengths):
         break
    print(lengths[i], end = ' ')

# While loop displays names based on length of words in list

while words != 4:
    if words in wordList:
        print("\nSelected words are:", words)
    break
```

## output

```
5 9 11 7 6 8 9 11 9 4
```

## sample desired output

Selected words are:

Abate

Chicanery

disseminate

gainsay

latent

aberrant

coagulate

dissolution

garrulous

Comment: can you provide a sample `words.txt` file. It doesnt have to be complete just something to get an idea of the format. I mean for instance is it one word per line or are the words space separated etc?

Comment: I edited my original post. I hope it is more helpful.

Comment: Yes sir, there are.

Comment: Thank you for your help by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you only want the first 10 words. There isn't much point reading all 4 lines. You can safely read just the 1st and save yourself some time.

```
#from itertools import chain

with open('words.txt') as f:

    # could raise `StopIteration` if file is empty
    words = next(f).strip().split()

    # to read all lines
    #words = []
    #for line in f:
    #    words.extend(line.strip().split())

    # more functional way
    # words = list(chain.from_iterable(line.strip().split() for line in f))

print("Selected words are:")
for word in words[:10]:
    if len(word) != 4:
        print(word)
```

There are a few alternative methods I left in there but commented out.

Edit using a while loop.

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if len(words[i]) != 4:
        print(words[i])
    i += 1
```

Since you know how many iterations you can do, you can hide the mechanics of the iteration using a `for` loop. A while does not facilitate this very well and is better used when you don't know how many iterations you will do.

Comment: Okay, this is getting close. However, I think I was wrong in what I asked. I created a list called lengths and I took the first ten words from the text file, put them into the list lengths[]  and printed which is what the output shows above. The values from the list lengths[] is what i'm trying to output I think.

Comment: I appreciate all your help paul. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but not all one line. Do you see the desired output I have above? I'm trying to get that.

Comment: If you think i'm insane. I don't blame you. haha

Comment: Yes sir. Instead of 5 I want it to print Abate.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. Yours worked wonderfully. I was just trying to do it with a while loop rather than a for.

Comment: oh ok. It's not really the right tool for the job. Since you know how many iterations you will do a `for` is best. I added how it can be done using a while loop, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Good point. I guess I was just curious to see how it was done. As you might have guessed i'm not a very experienced programmer. haha

Comment: If you want evidence of why its not good. I made a bug doing it the `while` way. Now corrected.

Comment: On the "more functional" way, you could avoid reading more than desired by using `itertools.islice` to slice the first ten values off without needing to read all of them. `words = list(islice(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, f)), 10))` (if on Py2, `from future_builtins import map` gets you the generator based Py3 `map` so this doesn't read the whole file). I also swapped the genexpr for `map` because it pushes all the work to the C layer, running faster (and we didn't need to `strip`, `split` implicitly strips leading and trailing whitespace).

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Thanks makes sense. I had intended the commented out code to show reading the whole file, buts its good to know how to do it more efficiently. Ultimately it still pulls a whole line from the file though right? The `strip`, `split` thing is good to know. I always found that a bit clunky.

Comment: @PaulRooney: Yar, it has to read a whole line at a time as written, but once it reaches 10 words, the rest of that line is thrown away, and the subsequent lines are never read in the first place. If the lines are huge, and you want to avoid overreading, you'd need to get more clever, processing the file by fixed size blocks instead of by line (which Python doesn't support quite as well). But usually lines aren't that long, so you're okay.

Answer (score 1):

To read all words from a text file, and print each of them unless they have a length of 4:

```
with open("words.txt","r") as wordsFile:
  words = wordsFile.read()
  wordsList = words.split()
  print ("Selected words are:")
  for word in wordsList:
    if len(word) != 4:     # ..unless it has a length of 4
      print (word)
```

Later in your question you write, "I'm trying to display the first 10 words "...).  If so, add a counter, and add a condition to print if its value is <= 10.

Answer (score 1):

While i'd use a for or a while loop, like Paul Rooney suggested, you can also adapt your code.
When you create the list lengths[], you create a list with ALL the lengths of the words contained in wordList.

You then cycle the first 10 lengths in lengths[] with the for loop;
If you need to use this method, you can nest a for loop, comparing words and lengths:

```
#lengths[] contains all the lengths of the words in wordList
lengths= [len(i) for i in wordList]
#foo[] cointains all the words in wordList
foo = [i for i in wordList]

#for the first 10 elements of lengths, if the elements isn't 4 char long
#print foo[] element with same index
for i in range(10):
    if lengths[i] != 4:
        print(foo[i])
    if i >= len(lengths):
        break
```

I hope this is clear and it's the answer you were looking for